# Проверка на правильность создании базы данных

Tags: база-данных, sql-server

Правильна ли взаимосвязь между таблицами?

Задание: Автотранспортное предприятие осуществляет перевозку пассажиров по городским маршрутам на маршрутных такси. Рейсы на маршрутах осуществляют водители на автобусах. На каждый рейс осуществляется назначение кондукторов. Рейс может обслуживаться одним или несколькими кондукторами или осуществляться без кондуктора.
Рейс характеризуется временем начала и окончания движения, количеством проданных билетов. Цена билета устанавливается отдельно для каждого маршрута. Автобусы характеризуются количеством мест, годом выпуска.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А у вас автобусы летают ;) Flight глаз режет - это рейс судна, обычно воздушного. По существу: У вас водитель всю жизнь ездит на одном автобусе ? а если его автобус сломался и он пересел на другой ...  И водитель закрепляется за маршрутом в целом, а разве информация какие водители на чем ездили в конкретные рейсы не нужна ? У кондуктора указан конкретный рейс, а история, что вчера он был на другом рейсе не нужна, только сиюминутная ?

Comment: Поменяйте Flight на Trip, чтобы Mike не ругался :)

Comment: Определитесь - что является независимыми сущностями. Например: водитель, автобус, кондуктор, маршрут. Тогда рейс - это комбинация водителя, автобуса и маршрута, плюс связь с набором кондукторов.

Comment: Имеет смысл добавить таблицу Schedule с расписанием - ссылка на маршрут, время отправления, время прибытия. Тогда запись в Trip это комбинация водителя, автобуса и записи из расписания, количество билетов, действительные даты отправления и прибытия. Для связки между рейсами и кондукторами нужна еще одна таблица linkTripConductor.